# how to add and custom rows in datagridview c#

Tags: c#

i have the following code

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name = "Product ID" + i + "";
}

for (int j = 0; i <= 5; j++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
}
```

but the code to add the rows does not work.  I need to add new row in that grid

Comment: What do you mean by custom rows?

Comment: "doesn't work" - I've got a pretty good grip on what it might be, but can you please expand on what doesn't work?  From looking at your code, it looks like you're not specifying what rows to add.  The definition of a gridview.Rows.Add requires a grid row to be passed in as a parameter, if memory serves correctly for this to work how I think you're trying to make it work.

Comment: @HariPrasad custom number of rows

Comment: You could add as many rows as you want, How many columns you have and what are the column types?

Comment: @user2366842 rows does not appear which appear only row of the column headings

Comment: @HariPrasad the number of columns are unlimited. depand on demand. the column type is string

Comment: @HariPrasad i mean, add rows in datagridview with unassigned column

Answer (score 0):

Change i <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount to

```
i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount
```

Change i to j in

```
for (int j = 0; i <= 5; j++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
}
```

The final result is

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
{
     dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name = "Product ID" + i + "";
}

 for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
 {
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
 }
```

Comment: but if the following code `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++) { dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name = "Product ID" + i + ""; }`  is not executed, the rows will appear. whether there is something wrong with the code